# How to create a material orientation using Abaqus python API - datums issue

Tags: abaqus

I am working on a software package that allows me to programmatically sweep through different geometries for a cylinder-like part, and both because my material is anisotropic and because it makes data analysis easier for my geometry, I need to define a cylindrical coordinate system `csys_cyl` for each generated part and then assign it as a material orientation. While I can easily do this in the GUI, the API is giving me one specific issue: **when assigning the material orientation, I cannot actually use the csys I generate as the `localCsys` argument to the `materialOrientation` function.** Instead, I have to use the below code, where I simply call the entry in `datums` that I got from the .jnl file I generated when using the GUI. Is there a better way to pass that `localCsys` argument that doesn't depend on a hard-coded ID number?

```
csys_cyl = part.DatumCsysByThreePoints(
    coordSysType=CYLINDRICAL, name='csys_cyl', origin=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), point1=(
    0.0, -1.0, 0.0), point2=(1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
part.MaterialOrientation(
    additionalRotationField='', additionalRotationType=ROTATION_NONE, angle=0.0,
    axis=AXIS_3, fieldName='',
    localCsys=part.datums[2], # what I'm forced to do
    # localCsys=csys_cyl, # what I would really like to do
    orientationType=SYSTEM,
    region=Region(cells=part.cells), stackDirection=STACK_3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the most effective solution was to use the `id` attribute of the csys object I generated. After interrogating variables, it seems that `csys_cyl`, the object returned by `DatumCsysByThreePoints` is just a generic feature, as is the object returned by Anbu's answer.

```
>>> print(csys_cyl)
({'children': '', 'id': 2, 'isOutOfDate': False, 'name': 'csys_cyl', 'parents': '', 'path': 'unknown', 'sketch': 'unknown'})
```

In contrast, the object returned from the `datums` dictionary is a specific `DatumCsys` type.

```
>>> print(part.datums[csys_cyl.id])
({'axis1': 'DatumAxis object', 'axis2': 'DatumAxis object', 'axis3': 'DatumAxis object', 'coordSysType': CYLINDRICAL, 'origin': 'DatumPoint object', 'pointOn': (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)})
```

Thus I found the solution to be using the `id` attribute of `csys_cyl` to get the `DatumCsys` from the dictionary, as shown below:

```
def add_cyl_csys(part):
    ###################################
    ## ADD CSYS AND MATERIAL ORIENTATIONS
    ###################################
    csys_cyl = part.DatumCsysByThreePoints(
        coordSysType=CYLINDRICAL, name='csys_cyl', origin=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), point1=(
        0.0, -1.0, 0.0), point2=(1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
    part.MaterialOrientation(
        additionalRotationField='', additionalRotationType=ROTATION_NONE, angle=0.0,
        axis=AXIS_3, fieldName='',
        localCsys=part.datums[csys_cyl.id],
        orientationType=SYSTEM,
        region=Region(cells=part.cells), stackDirection=STACK_3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing it as a *features* object under the *part object* should work.

> csys_cyl = part.DatumCsysByThreePoints(..., name='csys_cyl', ...)
>   type(csys_cyl)

will return `<type 'Feature'>` but the same can also be done with

> tmpVar = part.features['csys_cyl']
>   type(tmpVar)

will also return `<type 'Feature'>`. From the documentation, on *DatumCsys object*

> "The DatumCsys object has no direct constructor; it is created when a Feature object is created. ... "

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work - I receive the error message `localCsys; found Feature, expecting None`. This is the same exact error I originally received, and that makes some sense - the method you describe is basically just accessing the same object, which this function doesn't seem to like.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. `Index` of the `datums` is what `localCsys` is expecting! Glad you found.